# Execve() of more than one program

Tags: c, linux, fork, execve

Say I have two programs X and Y asking for input from `stdin`.  X and Y are run using `fork()` followed by `execve()` from a third from say A.

What is happening is X is scheduled first.  When X reaches the scanf statement, Y gets scheduled and X never gets an input. How do I take care of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have `A` mediate the input for `X` and `Y`. `A` can create a pipe to and from each child process. It can read a prompt from a pipe, write the prompt to standard output, read the response from standard input, and write the response to the pipe for the child process.